# Seting up a new ssh user on a centos box

Tags: ssh, centos

I'm new to setting up users on SSH. I have a centos bos, but not sure how to setup new users so that they are able to connect via ssh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a default configuration, with ssh enabled, all normal users are allowed to connect via ssh.

To create normal users you can use either the `system-config-users` tool, or the `useradd` command.

To check if sshd is running type

```
chkconfig --list sshd
```

And look for output similar to

```
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Moreover, the firewall must also allow ssh.  Default behavior during install is to have ssh enabled, with the firewall allowing access.  You can configure the firewall by using the `system-config-securitylevel-tui` utility and selecting 'Customize'.  Or you can check the firewall configuration directly by issuing

```
iptables -L
```

Comment: Don't forget to the firewall (defaults to allowing port 22 on CentOS)

Answer (score 2):

The manpage for `useradd` (and optionally `adduser`) commands should help you with setting up users on the box.

Answer (score 0):

just set up a new user they can automatically connect with ssh